# Best way to read, modify, and write XML

Tags: c#, xml

My plan is to read in an XML document using my C# program, search for particular entries which I'd like to change, and then write out the modified document.  However, I've become unstuck because it's hard to differentiate between elements, whether they start or end using XmlTextReader which I'm using to read in the file.  I could do with a bit of advice to put me on the right track.

The document is a HTML document, so as you can imagine, it's quite complicated.

I'd like to search for an element id within the HTML document, so for example look for this and change the src;

```
<img border="0" src="bigpicture.png" width="248" height="36" alt="" id="lookforthis" />
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If it's actually valid XML, and will easily fit in memory, I'd choose [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) (`XDocument`, `XElement` etc) every time. It's by far the nicest XML API I've used. It's easy to form queries, and easy to construct new elements too.

You can use XPath where that's appropriate, or the built-in axis methods (`Elements()`, `Descendants()`, `Attributes()` etc). If you could let us know what specific bits you're having a hard time with, I'd be happy to help work out how to express them in LINQ to XML.

If, on the other hand, this is HTML which *isn't* valid XML, you'll have a much harder time - because XML APIs generalyl expect to work with valid XML documents. You could use [HTMLTidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) first of course, but that *may* have undesirable effects.

For your specific example:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
foreach (var img in doc.Descendants("img"))
{
    // src will be null if the attribute is missing
    string src = (string) img.Attribute("src");
    img.SetAttributeValue("src", src + "with-changes");
}
```

Comment: I heartily agree! I had a couple of older apps I had to do the hard way with parsing and the like and L2X makes it so much easier and powerful.

Comment: Jon, you may find HtmlAgilityPack very useful, instead of worrying about valid XML, you can use APIs similar to XDocument on dirty, real-world HTML.

Comment: @Peter: Fortunately I've rarely had to work with dirty HTML - I've found myself using real XML more frequently. I'll bear it in mind though.

Answer (score 5):

Are the documents you are processing relatively small?  If so, you could load them into memory using an XmlDocument object, modify it, and write the changes back out.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("path_to_input_file");
// Make changes to the document.
using(XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter("path_to_output_file", Encoding.UTF8)) {
  xtw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented; // optional, if you want it to look nice
  doc.WriteContentTo(xtw);
}
```

Depending on the structure of the input XML, this could make your parsing code a bit simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tool I wrote to modify an IAR EWARM project (ewp) file, adding a linker define to the project. From the command line, you run it with 2 arguments, the input and output file names (*.ewp).

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Xml;

    namespace ewp_tool
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(args[0]);

                XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("/project/configuration[name='Debug']/settings[name='ILINK']/data/option[name='IlinkConfigDefines']/state");
                foreach(XmlElement x in list) {
                    x.InnerText = "MAIN_APP=1";
                }

                using (XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(args[1], Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    //xtw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented; // leave this out, it breaks EWP!
                    doc.WriteContentTo(xtw);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The structure of the XML looks like this

```
    <U+FEFF><?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <project>
      <fileVersion>2</fileVersion>
      <configuration>
        <name>Debug</name>
        <toolchain>
          <name>ARM</name>
        </toolchain>
        <debug>1</debug>

         ...

        <settings>
          <name>ILINK</name>
          <archiveVersion>0</archiveVersion>
          <data>

            ...

            <option>
              <name>IlinkConfigDefines</name>
              <state>MAIN_APP=0</state>
            </option>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have smaller documents which fit in computers memory you can use `XmlDocument`.
Otherwise you can use `XmlReader` to iterate through the document.

Using `XmlReader` you can find out the elements type using:

```
while (xml.Read()) {
   switch xml.NodeType {
     case XmlNodeType.Element:
      //Do something
     case XmlNodeType.Text:
      //Do something
     case XmlNodeType.EndElement:  
      //Do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the task in hand - (read existing doc, write, and modify in a formalised way) I'd go with [XPathDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathdocument(v=VS.90).aspx) run through an [XslCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx).

Where you can't formalise, don't have pre-existing docs or generally need more adaptive logic, I'd go with LINQ and XDocument like Skeet says.

Basically if the task is transformation then XSLT, if the task is manipulation then LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite tool for this kind of thing is [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  I use it to parse complex HTML documents into LINQ-queryable collections.  It is an extremely useful tool for querying and parsing HTML (which is often not valid XML).

For your problem, the code would look like:

```
var htmlDoc = HtmlAgilityPack.LoadDocument(stringOfHtml);
var images = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[id=lookforthis]");

if(images != null)
{
  foreach (HtmlNode node in images)  
  {  
      node.Attributes.Append("alt", "added an alt to lookforthis images.");  
  }  
}

htmlDoc.Save('output.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

One fairly easy approach would be to create a new `XmlDocument`, then use the `Load()` method to populate it.  Once you've got the document, you can use `CreateNavigator()` to get an `XPathNavigator` object that you can use to find and alter elements in the document.  Finally, you can use the `Save()` method on the `XmlDocument` to write the changed document back out.

Answer (score -1):

Just start by reading the documentation of the [Xml namespace on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml(VS.71).aspx). Then if you have more specific questions, post them here...